# How to pass a string into a function in Python

Tags: python, function, xpath, elementtree

Being new to Python, but still unescapable, I'm stuck on this problem. What I'm trying to do is pass a string into the function to get it `extend`ed.

**Here is what I have:**

```
def replace(source, destination):
    local_source = src_tree.find("source")
    local_destination = dest_tree.find("destination")
    local_destination.extend(local_source)

replace(source=".//animal-list/dog", destination=".//animal-list/dog")
```

This piece of code will work if I don't place it in a function. But because I have hundreds of these "`expend`" that I have to achieve, why not the good o' function calling.

**Originally I have this, and it works as what I need:**

```
src = src_tree.find('.//animal-list/dog')
dest = dest_tree.find('.//animal-list/dog')
dest.extend(src)
```

And what that would do is "replace" the `dest` dog with `src` dog. Works perfect, but I'm trying to make it into a function for easier use.

My question would be, what am I doing wrong in the function? Since it is tossing up a exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    replace(source=".//animal-list/dog", destination=".//animal-list/dog")
  File "test.py", line 13, in replace
    local_destination.extend(local_source)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Comment: `"source"` and `"destination"` shouldn’t be in quotes if you want to pass their values.

Comment: Strange how I thought I tried that and still gave me exception. I might be wrong, been going at this program (not particularly this problem) for over 12 hours now. (Rushing for Wednesday release). Problem is, I speak no Python before Wednesday.

Comment: @tyler Are you sure it's the _same_ exception?

Comment: It might have been a different exception. I think I just been in front of the computer for far too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've quoted things that should be variables (`source` and `destination`).
It should be:

```
def replace(source, destination):
    local_source = src_tree.find(source)
    local_destination = dest_tree.find(destination)
    local_destination.extend(local_source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are passing a literal string, instead of the variable

```
local_destination = dest_tree.find("destination")
```

Perhaps `dest_tree.find` is returning None because of that. Try this instead

```
local_destination = dest_tree.find(destination)
```

And likewise where you have used `"source"` instead of `source`